# Are EOS public and private keys case-sensitive?

Tags: keys

Are EOS public and private keys case-sensitive? (Needing to respect UPPERCASE vs. lowercase characters?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. EOS keys use a [Base 58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) encoding where uppercase and lowercase letters have different values.